# Oracle SQL - Joining list of values to a field with those values concatenated

Tags: sql, oracle

The title is a bit confusing, so I'll explain with an example what I'm trying to do.

I have a field called "modifier". This is a field with concatenated values for each individual. For example, the value in one row could be:

```
*26,50,4                 *
```

and the value in the next row

```
*4                       *
```

And the table (Table A) would look something like this:

```
Key    Modifier
1      *26,50,4                 *
2      *4                       *
3      *1,2,3,4                 *
```

The asterisks are always going to be in the same position (here, 1 and 26) with an uncertain number of numbers in between, separated by commas.

What I'd like to do is "join" this "modifier" field to another table (Table B) with a list of possible values for that modifier. e.g., that table could look like this:

```
ID         MOD
1          26
2          3
3          50
4          78
```

If a value in A.modifier appears in B.mod, I want to keep that row in Table A. Otherwise, leave it out. (I use the term "join" loosely because I'm not sure that's what I need here.)

Is this possible? How would I do it?

Thanks in advance!

edit 1: I realize I can use regular expressions and do a bunch of or statements that search for the comma-separated values in the MOD list, but is there a better way?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to do it is using TRIM, string concatenations and LIKE.

```
SELECT *
FROM tableA a
WHERE EXISTS(
   SELECT 1 FROM tableB b
   WHERE   
       ','|| trim( trim( BOTH '*' FROM a.Modifier )) ||','
       LIKE  '%,'|| b.mod || ',%'
);
```

Demo --> http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!4/1caa8/10

This query migh be still slow for huge tables (it always performs full scans of tables or indexes), however it should be faster than using regular expressions or parsing comma separated lists into individual values.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I will try this instead of using regexp.